# Undo edits based on sequence rather then layer selected in QGIS

Tags: qgis-3, undo-redo

I am used to undo feature of ArcMap that undo everything in sequence irrespective of the layer which is selected. In QGIS it only undo the edits made in the layer selected. Is there a way to change setting so as to undo the edits in sequence irrespective of the layer selected?

Comment: Don't think it's possible to undo edits in sequence, you can only undo edits for selected layers or for all layers at once.